# SwiftUI: Array Not Updating In All Views When Referencing The Same Observed Object

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui, observedobject

I am a fairly novice developer. I wrote an app for tracking indoor bouldering climbs all in 1 really large file. It was working fine, just hard to maintain. Now I am working on splitting it into multiple files and having some issues.

I created this view model to maintain all variables that are to be updated and then used by any view. This was the first piece I split out, and it worked just fine when all of my views were still in the same file.

I started by trying to get my titles to update in one file when a button was clicks in another file, with the title value maintained in what I called "VariableSetupModel". I got help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71975127/swiftui-view-not-updating-when-observed-object-changes-from-another-file/71975332#71975332) and now that is working. I tried to extend what I did for the text variable to an array I am maintaining in the same file. Here is the relevant part of this to my issue now.

File: VariableSetupModel

```
final class VariableSetupModel: ObservableObject {
    //static let shared = VariableSetupModel()
    
    //Climbs List
    @Published var climbs:[NSManagedObject] = []
}
```

Everything loads correctly when the app first builds. It pulls in the full list from CoreData and writes it to a local variable `climbs` for me to manipulate. But when I save a new climb to the array, it write to core data correctly, but my graphs all stay exactly the same. When I close the app and build again, the new climb I added then loads. I am using the same functions to load the graph on page load as I am when I hit save to reload, so I am stuck on how it's not working. I've spent a few days on this and made no progress.

Here is the view that adds a new climb.

File: CurrentProjectView

```
@EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VariableSetupModel
    
let contentView = ContentView()
    
var body: some View {

Button(action:{
                    contentView.addNewClimb(grade: viewModel.selectedGrade, attempts: viewModel.attemptsCount, status: viewModel.completeStatus)
                    
                    contentView.updateGraphArrays()
                    
                    print("submit button pressed: \(viewModel.climbs.first!)")
                }){
                    Text("Save")
                }
}
```

That print only shows the last item in the array when the page loaded. Does not include the new value added by `contentView.addNewClimb(grade: viewModel.selectedGrade, attempts: viewModel.attemptsCount, status: viewModel.completeStatus)`

I am printing after I write the new climb to `contentView.addNewClimb` so I went there to see what `viewModel.climbs` looks like there

File:ContentView

contentView.addNewClimb()

loadClimbs()

```
@ObservedObject var viewModel = VariableSetupModel()

var body: some View {
    VStack (alignment: .leading) {
        TodaysSessionView()

        CurrentProjectView().onAppear{
                    self.loadClimbs()
                    self.updateGraphArrays()
                }
    }.environmentObject(viewModel)
}


func addNewClimb(grade: Int, attempts: Int, status: String){
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        
        //where we are saving
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        // type of entity we are creating
        let entity =
            NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Climb",
                                       in: managedContext)!
        
        //creating one new instance
        let newClimb = NSManagedObject(entity: entity,
                                       insertInto: managedContext)
        
        
        //setting the value of each property
        newClimb.setValue(grade, forKeyPath: "grade")
        newClimb.setValue(attempts, forKeyPath: "attempts")
        newClimb.setValue(status, forKeyPath: "passfail")
        newClimb.setValue(Date(), forKeyPath: "climbdate")
    
        do {
            //try to save
            try managedContext.save()
            print("saved successfully!!!!")
            print(newClimb)
            
            self.loadClimbs()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            //if cannot save then print error
            print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
    }

func loadClimbs(){
        guard let appDelegate =
            UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
                return
        }
        
        let managedContext =
            appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSManagedObject>(entityName: "Climb")
        
        //sort
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "climbdate", ascending: false)
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        do {
            //set the climbs variable to all values
            viewModel.climbs = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)
            
            print("View model updated:", viewModel.climbs.first!)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
        }
        
        self.updateGraphArrays()
    }
```

In my addNewClimb function`print(newClimb)` prints the correct latest climb. So it is written to CoreData Correctly. Then I call `loadClimbs()` to write to `VariableSetupModel().climbs`.

In my loadClimbs function, `print("View model updated:", viewModel.climbs.first!)` also reflects the correct value.

So in order:
I hit submit, writes the new climb to core data, I then write the new core data values to viewModel.climbs in my `loadClimbs()` function and that still works. And then the last action in my submit button is to print the same viewModel.climbs value, and it only has a version of the array that appeared on page load, not the same version of the array printed in `loadClimbs()`. Therefore, my `TodaysSessionView()` view also does not get an updated version of `viewModel.climbs` either, which is what I ultimately want.

I have been running in circles around this and cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: Here is the view where `viewModel.climbs` is bring used. It ends up looking like this
[image]

```
struct TodaysSessionView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: VariableSetupModel
    let contentView = ContentView()
    
    var body: some View {
        let layout = [
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50)),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50)),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50)),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50)),
            GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 50))
        ]

        //Get last climb time
        let lastClimb = (viewModel.climbs.first as? Climb)?.climbdate
        
        if lastClimb ?? Date() < Date().addingTimeInterval(-28800) {
            Text("Last Session")
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.top)
                
        }else{
            Text("Todays Session")
                .font(.title)
                .padding(.top)
        }
        
        ScrollView{
            
                LazyVGrid (columns: layout, spacing: 15) {
                    ForEach(viewModel.climbs.reversed(), id: \.self){ thisClimb in
                        let gradeText = (thisClimb as? Climb)?.grade
                        let attemptsText = (thisClimb as? Climb)?.attempts
                        let passfailText = (thisClimb as? Climb)?.passfail ?? "climb string err"
                        let climbdateText = (thisClimb as? Climb)?.climbdate
                        
                        //how far back to pull into this. Maybe it should be -12 hours from the last climb
                        let cutoff = lastClimb!.addingTimeInterval(-28800)
                     
                        if climbdateText! > cutoff {
                            if passfailText == "Pass" {
                                VStack{
                                    ZStack {
                                        if attemptsText == 1 {
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color("whiteblack-bg"))
                                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                                .strokeBorder(viewModel.gradesColor[Int(gradeText!)], lineWidth: 3))

                                            ZStack{
                                                Circle()
                                                    .fill(viewModel.gradesColor[Int(gradeText!)])
                                                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                                    
                                                Circle()
                                                    .fill(Color("whiteblack-bg"))
                                                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                                
                                                Image(systemName: "bolt.fill")
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color("flashColor"))
                                                    .font(.footnote)
                                            }.offset(x: 0, y: 23)
                                            
                                        }else{
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color("whiteblack-bg"))
                                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                                .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                                .strokeBorder(viewModel.gradesColor[Int(gradeText!)], lineWidth: 3))
                                            
                                            ZStack{
                                                Circle()
                                                    .fill(viewModel.gradesColor[Int(gradeText!)])
                                                    .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                                
                                                Circle()
                                                    .fill(Color("whiteblack-bg"))
                                                    .frame(width: 18, height: 18)
                                                    
                                                Text("\(attemptsText!)")
                                                    .foregroundColor(Color("whiteblack"))
                                                    .font(.footnote)
                                            }.offset(x: 0, y: 23)
                                        }
                                        
                                        Text(viewModel.gradesV[Int(gradeText!)])
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                //Didnt pass
                                VStack{
                                    ZStack{
                                        Circle()
                                            .fill(Color("whiteblack-bg"))
                                            .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                            .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                                                        .strokeBorder(viewModel.gradesColor[Int(gradeText!)], lineWidth: 3))
                                        
                                        ZStack{
                                            Circle()
                                                .fill(Color(.red))
                                                .frame(width: 22, height: 22)
                                                
                                            
                                            
                                            Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                                                .font(.footnote)
                                        }.offset(x: 0, y: 22)
                                        
                                        Text(viewModel.gradesV[Int(gradeText!)])
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add how are you using the `viewModel.climbs` in your view

Comment: I have added that to the bottom.

Comment: ContentView should not be instantiated like that, it should be in somewhere in `body` (either of WindowScene or parent view). As well in button action view should not be used (it is a copy of your view, because view is a value), etc... Take a couple of SwiftUI tutorials.

Comment: Can you expand on that? As far as I can tell, the contentView stuff all works. And when I moved it into the body, that didn't work. It seems like my view model values is what is being duplicated but I can't tell why. Of course I could be wrong. You said to do SwiftUI tutorials, what specifically should I look up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it working. All I had to do was move the functions I had in my view to my viewModel. Im guessing to keep everything in the same scope. My guess is that everything in ContentView was it's own copy. I'm not 100% certain on that, but it works now.